# MVC - Redirect after authentication and remember

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, authentication, redirecttoaction

I have a MVC Login page where I authenticate the user with an AJAX post method.

I want to redirect the user from Home/Index to another controller method Home/Main once the username and password are authenticated.

Here's my home controller:

```
Function Index() As ActionResult     
Return View() 
End Function 

Function Main() As ActionResult
Return View() 
End Function
```

Here is my ajax post method:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#BtnLogin').click(function () {
                var userInfo = {
                    UserName: $('#txtusername').val(),
                    Password: $('#TxtPassword').val()
                };

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Content("~/api/Users/CheckUser")',
                       type: 'POST',
                       data: JSON.stringify(userInfo),
                       dataType: 'json',
                       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                       success: function (responseData) {
                           for (var i = 0; i < responseData.length; i++) {
                               if (responseData[i].isErrorBool == '1') {
                                   document.getElementById("LblErrors").innerHTML = responseData[i].isErrorMessage;
                               }
                               else {
                                   //redirect
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   });
               });
           });
    </script>
```

And my Web API:

```
<HttpPost>
Public Function CheckUser(LGIN As LoginModel) As List(Of VerifyReturnLogin)
    Dim ReturnJson = Nothing
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    Dim sw As New StringWriter(sb)
    Try
        Using jsonWriter As JsonWriter = New JsonTextWriter(sw)
            jsonWriter.WriteStartArray()
            jsonWriter.WriteStartObject()

            Dim c As List(Of UserProfile) = userRepository.CheckUser(LGIN.UserName.Trim, LGIN.Password.Trim)
            If c.Count = 0 Or c Is Nothing Then
                jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("isErrorBool")
                jsonWriter.WriteValue("1")
                jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("isErrorMessage")
                jsonWriter.WriteValue("Wrong Username or Password.")
                jsonWriter.WriteEndObject()
                jsonWriter.WriteEndArray()
                ReturnJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of VerifyReturnLogin))(sb.ToString)
                Return ReturnJson
            Else
                'Redirect to Home/Main
            End If
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Function
```

Where is the best place to redirect? Client or Server side?

And After login, is it wise to use Sessions in MVC like they are used in ASP.net, to ensure that the user is authenticated to go to Home/Main on every refresh?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ok, I delete my answer. I thought the question was about redirection and not authentication. You asked how users are usually redirected in asp.net MVC framewrok, I posted my opinion, showed some code, and you say that it's not the same authentication method. I ve never seen redirecting in this framework through writing JS. But ok, as u wish.

Answer (score 0):

You should use in javascript `window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";` when you have

> //redirect

Comment: Thanks. How can I make sure everytime the user goes to Home/Main that he goes through Home/Login first?

Comment: You use Authorizate attribute.